# Notepad++ Quickly replace text as HTML comment

Tags: html

Is there a way i can type a block of text, then highlight it all and quickly replace it as an html comment?

So

```
 sdfkjlsfklsdjflksahflkdhlfka
 kldjfsdklfjsldkjsl
```

Gets replaced as

```
<!-- sdfkjlsfklsdjflksahflkdhlfka
 kldjfsdklfjsldkjsl -->
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approach but customizable would be to replace the part you selected with the same text but adding custom tags around it.

Might even be macro'able.

[image: RegEx Replace Comment]

PHP Version:

[image: phptest]

Comment: I kind of got it to work. If it's just a random text file i can use that to comment blocks of text HTML style, but if i try to comment blocks of text in a PHP file, it will instead comment the entire file out, not just my selection. Not sure what the issue is

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza the tick next to "Replace All" called `[X] In selection` has to be ticked. If you have all settings like this it works.

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza just checked, in a .php file you need to first select the text then go to the replace window and tick the `In selection`

Comment: just not working for me. doing everything like you are. it ignores my selection and tries to select the whole file instead of just the selection. i see it works for you though so i'll mark it and figure it out. thanks. note: i'm trying to use html comments for the html stuff inside my php file. don't think it should matter but yea

Answer (score 1):

If Notepad++ has detected that the page is html, or you have selected html under the languages menu you can use: Ctrl + Shift + Q

Or alternatively Edit > Comment/Uncomment > Block Comment

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+k
check documentation [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Notepad-plus-plus_5.9.html)